# asp.net mvc view only returns when using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-binding

So I've been working on a simple asp.net application this week. And today I had a problem with a razor view not returning anything to my controller method. The view had to return several objects in a List<>.

I finally got it working by passing a list of objects to the view and looping through them with a 'for' loop. I also tried it today with a foreach loop but that didn't work.

I've got the following GET method that passes a list of empty objects to the view:

```
// GET: MpSwitches/CreateSeveral
    public ActionResult CreateSeveral()
    {
        var mpSwitches = new List<MpSwitch>
        {
            new MpSwitch() {IpAdress = "1"},
            new MpSwitch() {IpAdress = "2"},
            new MpSwitch() {IpAdress = "3"},
            new MpSwitch() {IpAdress = "4"},
            new MpSwitch() {IpAdress = "5"}
        };
        // Check if the user gets redirected to this method because of a First Time Startup.
        if (TempData["RedirectFirstTimeStartup"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.FirstTime =
                "Je bent doorgestuurd naar deze pagina omdat er nog geen MP-switches in de database staan.";
            return View(mpSwitches);
        }
        return View(mpSwitches);
    }
```

Then there is the View:

```
@model List<WebInterface.Models.MpSwitch>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create several";
}
<h2>Create several</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MpSwitch</h4>
        @if (ViewBag.FirstTime != null)
        {
            <div class="alert-warning">
                <b>Opgelet! </b>@ViewBag.FirstTime
            </div>
        }
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].IpAdress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].IpAdress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].IpAdress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My question is: Why doesn't this same code work with a 'foreach' instead of the 'for' loop?

The code that isn't working currently:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.IpAdress, htmlAttributes: new { 
    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IpAdress, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.IpAdress, "", new 
    { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Now when using the foreach loop the following controller method doesn't get a parameter (the parameter is null).

```
    // POST: MpSwitches/CreateSeveral
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific 
    properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateSeveral([Bind(Include = 
    "Id,IpAdress,LastSyncDateTime")] List<MpSwitch> mpSwitches)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var mpSwitch in mpSwitches)
            {
                db.MpSwitches.Add(mpSwitch);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(mpSwitches);
    }
```

And i get the following error: [Link to image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3uu.png)

Comment: Could you post the code which is not working?

Comment: code with foreach!

Comment: I added the not working code

Comment: Any error are you getting ?

Comment: Added a link to a screenshot of my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the rendered html when using `foreach loop` you will get this

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="item_IpAdress" name="item.IpAdress" value="" type="text">
```

and when you use `for loop` it will be like this

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="MpSwitch_0__IpAdress" name="MpSwitch[0].IpAdress" value="" type="text">
```

since you are using `List<MpSwitch>` so when you submit the form using `for loop` in  `MpSwitch[0].IpAdress` new value of `IpAddress` will be assigned to `MpSwitch` on `index 0` while in `foreach loop` value will be assigned to `item.IpAdress` and when you submit `List<MpSwitch>` will be `null` because to bind complex objects, you have to provide an index for each item. you can also check this [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting is that when you use a `foreach` instead of a `for`, you don't have an index of the item and the names/ids of the HTML elements overlap each other. Take a look at the HTML source that you're sending to the browser (View Page Source or Inspect Element), and you'll notice that the name is `MpSwitch[0].IpAddress`, etc. When you use a `foreach` it will only be `MpSwitch.IpAddress`. That can't be serialized into a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC ModelBinder needs the index of the list items to correctly bind them to the ViewModel.

If you use a `for` loop, the correct index is incorporated into the `id` and `name` attributes of the generated HTML `<input>` elements.

You can also incorporate the index explicitly, see [Binding arrays with missing elements in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564991/binding-arrays-with-missing-elements-in-asp-net-mvc).