# Unable to pass model from a post form to a controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem (or I don't understand how forms work) with passing a model to a controller from a form. I have a model called `EmptySurveyViewModel`, that has a list consisting of `EmptyQuestionViewModel`. This question model has a property `Answer` that is empty, and is to be filled by the form. However, one survey has many questions, and at the end i want to pass a model to the controller that is a `EmptySurveyViewModel`, containing a list of `EmptyQuestionViewModel`, that each has the `Answer` property. That property can be filled in different ways, depending on the type of the question. My problem is that if I don't have the `if` statement (see below), all questions are displayed as radio style questions, and the model passed to the controller has only questions that have the `Answer` property filled. However, when i add the `if` (i intend to add other `if`s, to catch all possible types), only some questions are listed, and when i submit the form, the model is completely empty (it's not `null`, but its property `Questions` is `null`. I think the first situation (without the `if`) can be dealt with by other logic later on, but returning an empty list can't. Why is that happening?

The Models:

```cs
public class EmptySurveyViewModel {
    //Something else here
    public List<EmptyQuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class EmptyQuestionViewModel {
    //Something else here
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```cs
@model cq.Models.EmptySurveyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" })) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
        if (Model.Questions[i].Type == "Single choice") {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].Answer, "foo")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].Answer, "bar")
        }
        <br />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And the Action in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(EmptySurveyViewModel survey) {
    //Do something with the survey here
}
```

Comment: please check with FormCollection add in Action parameter like eg, [HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(EmptySurveyViewModel survey,FormCollection fc) {
    //Do something with the survey here
} if a value occurs in form?

Comment: @jishansiddique As it turns out it was a problem of the model binder not understanding the model, as Andrei suggested. Thank you for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens because you are skipping some of the indices. So when the data is posted back, you maybe post objects with indices 0, 1, 3, while 2 is missing because it happened to be filtered out by `if`. That breaks the continuity of the collection, something model binding cannot deal with. More details can be found in this [Haacked post](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

There are few possible solutions:

1. Add other if's to cover all question types. That will make sure there are no skips.
2. As Phil suggests in the post, add a hidden `Index` field to each question (also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3564991/728795)). Note that this will cause only rendered questions to be posted back.
3. Render filtered out questions as hidden inputs entirely, again avoiding skipping any of them.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the model to bind when I added the other types of questions. I had a problem with the model not binding if the line of answered questions was broken(a question was left unanswered), but i fixed it by adding a hidden input for a hidden value called "Token" in the model. That fixed my issue, thank you again :) 
P.S. MVC model binder is dumb, I feel there can be a more intuitive way to do this in my opinion